# Webforms ScriptResource.axd ArgumentTypeException - Ajax

Tags: .net, ajax

Using .Net 4.5, I have a set of  controls contained within an UpdatePanel. One of these controls is a drop down that does a partial page postback.

If I enter this form and click the submit button which is outside of the UpdatePanel and then select an item in the drop down within the UpdatePanel, Im getting a js error from ScriptResource.axd

Sys>ArgumentTypeExceltion: Object of type object cannot be converted to type string. Parameter name value.

The server side postback event on the drop down is then not fired

Answer (score 1):

In this case, this was due to the form containing a hidden field with ID of "action"